# how to redirect to a route like deals/view/{id}

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-5, routes

I am trying to `redirect` to a route from a `controller` in `laravel`. I am doing this:

```
return redirect()->route('deals/view/' . $inputs['id']);
```

The `route` defined is like this:

```
Route::get('deals/view/{id}', 'DealsController@view');
```

when the code runs it throws this `exception`:

> InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 314: Route
>   [deals/view/1] not defined.

When I try to access it directly in the `browser` it works fine. How to do it? Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your route to this

```
Route::get('deals/view/{id}', ['as' => 'deals', 'uses' => 'DealsController@view']);
```

and your redirect to this

```
return redirect()->route('deals', array($inputs['id']))
```

Comment: glad could help :) @Saani

Answer (score 0):

Try passing second argument as a array.

In the route() function there should be name of the route not url, so instead of `deals/view` use name of the route.

`return redirect()->route('viewdeal', array($inputs['id']));`

So your full code will be like this

`Route::get('/deal/view/{id}', array("as" => "viewdeal", "uses" => "DealsController@viewdeal"));`

Comment: passing id in argument gives this: `Route [deals/view/] not defined`